# CMDER\vendor\conemu-maximus5\..\init.bat"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: console, init, cmder

Can you tell me please, what this CMDER error means? **CMDER\vendor\conemu-maximus5..\init.bat"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file**. My CMDER lost its colors (like three times before) so I download new one for Win 10 and it throws me this error. Does somebody know what happened? 
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You're running it from wrong folder, where init.bat is absent. Try ConEmu, it is genuine and has no dependencies ;)

Comment: I installed it again and it works. Dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file init.bat is in your-path-to-cmder/Cmder/vendor folder. If not, check if your antivirus put it in quarantine. Avast antivirus do it. Add a exception for init.bat in the antivirus, download and reinstall cmder.

Comment: The OP problem happened to me and there is nothing in quarantine

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I discovered that the `init.bat` was not copied when I re-installed cmder. Despite having UAC and virus turned off, the access to the file would be denied, regardless of whether I'd use `xcopy` in admin-run cmd or explorer drag-and-drop.

The other users' hints about the file init.bat being allegedly quarantined by avast or what not, turned out to be completely missed in my case.

What **I did wrong** was how I installed (updated) cmder.

- I first created a fresh new directory to be my cmder home directory, at `C:\cmder`
- I opened (as opposed to *extracted*) the `cmder_mini.zip` download
- I selected all the contents of the archive and copied over to the cmder home directory.

Then I realized the init.bat never got copied from the archive due to access denied.

**Instead**

- Extract the zip archive
- Drag the entire `cmder_mini` unpacked folder to your desired destination (`C:\`)
- **Rename** it to your liking (from `cmder_mini` to `cmder`)

You get the difference, right? This way the `init.bat` file will "move along". No pesky message upon creating a console anymore.